# Connect-PnPOnline does not work with build agent

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint-online

The following powershell snippet from the script works fine in a local machine:

```
$SharepointConnection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $ConfigInfo.AProcessDef.ASharePointUrl.ToString().Trim() -Credential $SharepointCredential -ReturnConnection -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

But it fails while running the very same snippet by a Azure DevOps build agent (self-hosted agent behind a proxy server) on a build VM machine. The build machine is behind a proxy and it is already configured. I already checked with InvokeWebRequest to reach organization's local intranet and internet and it worked fine well. I am getting the following exception with Connect-PnPOnline:

```
 System.Net.WebException The remote name could not be resolved:
```

I logged into the vm machine , executed the snippet without any error. I can connect to the domainname.sharepoint.com.

Some hint is appreciated to address this issue.

Comment: The error ` System.Net.WebException The remote name could not be resolved:` usually indicates there's something wrong with proxy or DNS.
 What's the result if you ping the url `ping xxx.com` locally and use self-agent to call the command-line task with command `ping some-domain-that-doesnt-exist.com`? Any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the following snippet within the powershell script:
       [system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy = new-object system.net.webproxy($ConfigInfo.Proxy.ToString().Trim()) 
       [system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.credentials = 
          [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
       [system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = $true

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.